# Custom TileProvider for OpenWeatherMap not showing precipitation tiles

Tags: android, google-maps, openweathermap

I am trying to implement `TileProvider` on Weather app by using OpenWeatherMap.org. Problem is that it is not showing precipitation on Google map. My java code of `MapsActivity`

```
    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

        private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
        private static String OWM_TILE_URL = "http://tile.openweathermap.org/map/%s/%d/%d/%d.png appid=ffe8e3ec39ae79c82c32ebba7059ab14";
        private Spinner spinner;
        private String tileType = "clouds";
        private TileOverlay tileOver;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
            spinner = findViewById(R.id.tileType);

    // String tileName
            String[] tileName = new String[]{"Clouds", "Temperature","Precipitations", "Snow", "Rain", "Wind", "Sea level press."};

            ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, tileName);

            spinner.setAdapter(adpt);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    // Check click
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            tileType = "clouds";
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            tileType = "temp";
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            tileType = "precipitation";
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            tileType = "snow";
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            tileType = "rain";
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            tileType = "wind";
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            tileType = "pressure";
                            break;

                    }

                    if (mMap != null) {
                        tileOver.remove();
                        setUpMap();
                    }


                }
            });
            setUpMapIfNeeded();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            setUpMapIfNeeded();
        }

        /**
         * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play 
          services APK is correctly
         * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This 
          will ensure that we only ever
         * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
         * <p/>
         * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
         * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a 
         prompt for the user to
         * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
         * <p/>
         * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the 
          prompt and correctly
         * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
         * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be `enter code here`            * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
         * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
         */
        private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
            // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
            if (mMap == null) {
                // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
                ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                        .getMapAsync(this);
                // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
                if (mMap != null) {
                    setUpMap();
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move 
         the camera. In this case, we
         * just add a marker near Africa.
         * <p/>
         * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
         */
        private void setUpMap() {
            // Add weather tile
            //tileOver = mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(createTilePovider()));

            tileOver = mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(createTransparentTileProvider()));
        }

        private TileProvider createTransparentTileProvider() {
            return new TransparentTileOwm(tileType);
        }

    // tileProvider method
        private TileProvider createTilePovider() {
            TileProvider tileProvider = new UrlTileProvider(256, 256) {
                @Override
                public URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {
                    String fUrl = String.format(OWM_TILE_URL, tileType == null ? "clouds" : tileType, zoom, x, y);
                    URL url = null;
                    try {
                        url = new URL(fUrl);
                    }
                    catch(MalformedURLException mfe) {
                        mfe.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return url;
                }
            } ;

            return tileProvider;
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        }
    }
```

and below XML code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment  android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/tileType"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I have followed this tutorial below in order to implement tile provider
https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2015/03/android-google-map-add-weather-data-tile-2.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `OWM_TILE_URL` template:

```
private static String OWM_TILE_URL = "http://tile.openweathermap.org/map/%s/%d/%d/%d.png appid=ffe8e3ec39ae79c82c32ebba7059ab14";
```

is incorrect: you miss `?` symbol before `appid` parameter. Should be:

```
private static String OWM_TILE_URL = "http://tile.openweathermap.org/map/%s/%d/%d/%d.png?appid=ffe8e3ec39ae79c82c32ebba7059ab14";
```